# Google maps with JQuery Mobile and jquery-ui-map

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, html5-canvas

I'm using the jQuery UI Map libary (https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) to display a map on my html5 mobile website, however i'm only getting a grey square no matter what i try.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <title>test</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://local url/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://local url/js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="main">

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>
      TEST SITE
    </p>
    <p>
        <canvas id="map_canvas" style="width:50%;height:50%"></canvas>    
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#map_canvas').gmap();
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '42.345573,-71.098326' });               
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 8 });
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result i get is this:

http://upload.mattie-systems.nl/uploads/28217-knipsel.png

Any help would be greatley appreciated!

Comment: dont use `.ready()` with jQuery Mobile. You can fix this by wrapping your code inside `$(document).on('pageshow', '#main', function () { your code here });`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, however the issue remains. I still don't see a map, just a grey square.

Comment: make sure you're using correct code check this http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html

Comment: As far as i can tell i am using the correct code (mostly from: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code) however if i use the code from your link i still get the same issue.

Comment: In that page, it uses `.on('pageinit')` event to load maps. you can use `.on('pagebeforeshow')` or `.on('pageshow')`. Does it work on a desktop browser?

Comment: Try changing the height of you container to a fixed amount (eg 300px) to see if that works. Give a jsfiddle if it doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

Map can't  be shown on canvas element, it must be DIV like this:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Also don't use percentages for map height, ether use px, em or use css like in my example to fill working page.

### Working HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"/>
        <style>
            #map_canvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left:0;
                right:0;
            }
        </style>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>              
        <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('pageshow', '#main', function() {  
                $('#map_canvas').gmap();
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': '42.345573,-71.098326' });               
                $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 8 });
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');
            });
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="main">          
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    TEST SITE
                </p>
                <p>
                    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to find more about this topic + examples then take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)**.

Comment: *sigh*  THANK YOU!!!!!! All the tutorials used "#map_canvas" so I assumed i sould use the <canvas> :) Never thought of using a div instead of it, really really thanks :)

Comment: awsome, how powerful is `$('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh');`